# Need to read OBD-II steering angle PID on 2009 Toyota Camry

Tags: toyota, obd-ii, camry

My graduation project is about developing the car side mirror. And for that purpose I need some data from my 2009 Toyota Camry. I have searched for the PID's (parameter ID's) for some sensors, but I couldn't find them, and that is what I am writing to you for.

I will be more than thankful if you provide me with the PID's I need.

I need the PID for the following sensors in the 2009 Toyota Camry :
1- steering angle.
2- gear selection (the address that gives me the current gear engaged [P/R/N/D/L]).

And if anyone knows where to obtain a paid table for the PID's of 2009 Toyota Camry I don't mind buying it.

Thanks

Comment: This is a specific question of a development project that is entirely automobile based. As such OP is looking for specific technical information that's related to auto mechanics. This seems to be well within the scope of this site.

Comment: The place to subscribe escapes me at the moment. Access to Toyota's mode 21 PIDs is NOT cheap  Expect to pay thousands of US dollars and there may be other requirements to subscribe that would exclude you from being able to.

Comment: I would just gather the raw CAN data, way less coding, faster response times. Unless the application is to be universal to all makes and models and the fact you only need two data fields I would always just read the raw data.